How to display HTML as code formatted for specific programming languages
I came across a website that displayed some SQL code. Inspecting the element, I saw that there was SQL specific classes and styles applied (ex. the table names were blue).
Here is what I saw:

My question is how is this done easily? Is there some front-end package or library that can make code blocks formatted correctly to a certain language like C#, SQL, HTML, etc.?

The site is using likely highlight.js which is a CSS/JS library that handles code highlighting for many languages.
